# scala with nscala-time - no minutes function

Tags: scala, jodatime

I am writing my first Scala application and I am having a bit of a problem with `nscala-time` wrapper for `joda-time` library.

I have a class like this:

```
package domain

import org.joda.time.{Period => JodaPeriod}

case class GroundTime(val minimum: JodaPeriod, standard: JodaPeriod)
```

(I renamed `Period` class because I already have `Period` class in my domain)

Now, in my `specs2` test I wanted to write something like:

```
"check standard ground time constraint" in {
  import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

  val groundTime = GroundTime(minimum=10 minutes, standard=15 minutes)
```

but I am getting an error `cannot resolve symbol minutes`.

I wanted to do something like snippet that is on `github` page of `nscala-time` library:

```
2.hours + 45.minutes + 10.seconds
// returns com.github.nscala_time.time.DurationBuilder
// (can be used as a Duration or as a Period)
```

Comment: Why don't you want to write `val groundTime = GroundTime(minimum=10.minutes, standard=15.minutes)`?

Comment: @BobDalgleish : and what would that change in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I digged into `specs2` code a little bit and I discovered that by extending `Specification` you also import something like `TimeConversions` from `specs2` and there was `minutes` that "shadowed" `minutes` function from `nscala-time` (I am saying shadows but it was probably a problem with implicit conversions).

But also I discovered trait called `NoTimeConversions` from `specs2` so now when I write

```
MySpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions
```

I can write `10.minutes` and it produces `DurationBuilder` which I wanted in the first place.

Comment: You should also import `scala.language.postfixOps` **due to [Scala's feature modularization](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/modularizing-language-features.html)** - in future versions, you will have to specifically enable postfix operators like `10 minutes`, otherwise the compiler will report an error (instead of a warning). Related info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011204/scalas-postfix-ops). (Readding the contents of the withdrawn answer as a comment.)