# Scala: Anonymous function return type

Tags: function, scala, types, return, anonymous

Why do i have to declare the return type this way:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x) product: Int
  println(n(5))
}
```

If i remove the type, i'd have to assign it before printing:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x) product
  val a = n(5)
  println(n(5))
}
```

this variant gives an error - why?

```
val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x) product
println(n(5))
```

I get the following error (using Scala-ide):

> recursive value n needs type  Test.scala  /src    line 5  Scala Problem

Comment: I don't get any error when running the code you are posting on a REPL. Can you please detail what error are you having?

Comment: i added it to my question :)

Comment: Works fine with Scala 2.10.2. What version are you using?

Comment: Used the wrong snippet to test. It also happens with 2.10.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing a problem with semicolon inference, due to the use of a postfix operator (`product`):

```
// Error
val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x) product
println(n(5))

// OK - explicit semicolon
val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x) product;
println(n(5))

// OK - explicit method call instead of postfix - I prefer this one
val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x).product
println(n(5))

// OK - note the newline, but I wouldn't recommend this solution!
val n = (x: Int) => (1 to x) product

println(n(5))
```

Essentially, Scala gets confused as to where an expression ends, so you need to be a little more explicit, one way or another.

Depending on compiler settings, this feature may be disabled by default - see [Scala's "postfix ops"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011204/scalas-postfix-ops) and [SIP-18: Modularizing Language Features](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nlkvpoIRkx7at1qJEZafJwthZ3GeIklTFhqmXMvTX9Q/edit?pli=1)