# scala sys.process_ illegal start of simple expression error

Tags: scala

I got an error "illegal start of simple expression" in scala while trying to do this:

```
def test() = {
    val h = "ls"!
    if (h != 0)
        println("error")

}
```

this is the error

```
[error]         if (h != 0)
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala compiler is getting confused here because you are calling `!` as a postfix operator. It can't figure out which version to use and where to place the implied semicolon. You can either add a semicolon like this:

```
def test() = {
    val h = "ls"!;
    if (h != 0)
        println("error")
}
```

or call it as a method:

```
def test() = {
    val h = "ls".!
    if (h != 0)
        println("error")
}
```

or add a new line:

```
def test() = {
    val h = "ls"!

    if (h != 0)
        println("error")
}
```

Comment: Or add blank line. Note that it is syntax, independent of the overload.

Comment: @som-snytt indeed. I didn't want to suggest a new line approach, but I added it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice to use a postfix operator is to use dot `.` operator. You should invoke it like `val h = "ls".!`

It makes code less ambiguous as semicolon is optional in Scala and compiler might treat it as an infix notation.

From **Scala** doc:

> This style is unsafe, and should not be used. Since semicolons are
>   optional, the compiler will attempt to treat it as an infix method if
>   it can, potentially taking a term from the next line.

For full reference see this link: [Suffix Notation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html#suffix-notation). This post may also be helpful [Scala's "postfix ops"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011204/scalas-postfix-ops).