# scala: error: recursive value needs type

Tags: scala, recursion

I'm trying to write a short snippet of scala code to understand parenthesesless method and postfixOps.
Here is my code:

```
import scala.language.postfixOps

object Parentheses {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val person = new Person("Tom", 10);
        val tomAge = person getAge
        println(tomAge)
    }


    class Person(val name: String, val age: Int) {
        def getAge = {
            age
        }
    }

}
```

However, while compiling it, I have a problem says:

```
error: recursive value tomAge needs type
        println(tomAge)
```

If I replace the method call `person getAge` to `person.getAge`, the program will run correctly.
so why the function call of `person getAge` failed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Postfix notation should be used with care - see sections `infix notation` and `postfix notation` [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html).

> This style is unsafe, and should not be used. Since semicolons are
>   optional, the compiler will attempt to treat it as an infix method if
>   it can, potentially taking a term from the next line.

Your code will work (with a compiler warning) if you append a `;` to `val tomAge = person getAge`.

Comment: that's a fantastic explanaition! Thank's for sharing, I looked the doc you share, very helpful!

Comment: Thanks, @Damian Lattenero.  It's a rather tricky "anomaly".  Had the following `println` code line not been referencing `tomAge`, the error message `error: Int does not take parameters` would have been a little more revelatory.

Comment: I was trying to find it in a web compiler and you just comment and it was great

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation and the helpful doc!

Answer (score 1):

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val person = new Person("Tom", 10);
    val tomAge = person getAge; ///////////
    println(tomAge)
}
```

Your code does't work because you need to add the ";" in the infix operations!

I tryed your example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_scala_online.php) and worked just fine!

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011204/scalas-postfix-ops), the accepted answer shows another example

Comment: @Changada Li! Fantastic! No problem I have always loved to help, when I answered the other pal answered first hahaha but well... Glad to help anyway