# what is difference between (1 to 10 by 3) toList and (1 to 10 by 3).toList in scala(or intellij problem?)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

if this question is stupid, please understand.

I'm starting to learn scala with basic grammar.

But I don't understand why one is error other is not. I tested this with scala worksheet

```
val range = 1 to 10 by 3 toList
println(s"$range") //error
```

but the below is the List(actually Seq)

```
val range = (1 to 10 by 3).toList
println(s"$range") //no problem
```

I am using intellij 2018.2 ultimate edit.

**Edit**: Image was changed. I attached capture that is included error message not warning.
[image]

**Edit**: I thought it is intellij version problem, but still doesn't work

Comment: That is actually not an error. Its just that IntelliJ is confused by the compiler warning about the usage of postfix syntax. I will strongly advise you to start with more explicit syntax like `val range = Range(1, 11, 3).toList` or `Range.inclusive(1, 10, 3)` instead of `(1 to 10 by 3).toList` which involves the `implicits` over `Int` and postfix syntax. Once you have gotten a good grasp of things then you can move to more fancier stuff like this.

Comment: it'a warning telling you should enable postfixOps if you use them (as you do) `import scala.language.postfixOps`

Comment: you can go into scala-> general -> advance language feature (tick mark it)

Comment: It's worth noting that the `List` object has a `.range()` method: `List.range(1,10,3)` No `.toList` conversion needed.

Comment: it works for me in 2.11... please check your Scala version

Comment: @BalajiReddy used scala 2.12.7 but not work

Comment: not sure why. its not a syntactical error. I also use intellij IDE

Comment: @HackingJ you need to end the line with post-fix operator either with [`;` or new line or defining a `val`, `def` after the post-fix operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53427053/432903).

Answer (score 1):

Either should work. In scala you can omit `.` with space for method invocation, which is probably broken version of haskell way. I think space is not recommended in scala as per official doc - [STYLE GUIDE - METHOD INVOCATION](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html)

Example:

```
scala> val data = "guitar"
data: String = guitar

scala> data.toUpperCase
res8: String = GUITAR
```

you can use space instead of `.`,

```
scala> data toUpperCase
<console>:13: warning: postfix operator toUpperCase should be enabled
by making the implicit value scala.language.postfixOps visible.
This can be achieved by adding the import clause 'import scala.language.postfixOps'
or by setting the compiler option -language:postfixOps.
See the Scaladoc for value scala.language.postfixOps for a discussion
why the feature should be explicitly enabled.
       data toUpperCase
            ^
res9: String = GUITAR
```

Since `.toUpperCase` is used after the data-structure without `.` (it is called [postfix Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24416443/432903)) and compiler is simply warning about that. It can be fixed as the warning says,

```
scala> import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.language.postfixOps

scala> data toUpperCase
res10: String = GUITAR
```

Same thing applies to your example. From readability perspective dot makes more readable in your example.

```
scala> (1 to 10 by 3).toList
res9: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 7, 10)
```

ALSO, post-fix operators could lead into bugs. For example, `1 + "11" toInt` apply the `toInt` at the end of the computation but maybe what I wanted was `1 + "11".toInt`

ALSO, ALSO regarding your bug you need to yell at compiler to stop chaining on `toList` with `;` or a new line after post-fix operator. Or you can use `val`, `def` after post-fix operator that way compiler knows it is different context now.

```
scala> :paste

    import scala.language.postfixOps
    val range = 1 to 10 by 3 toList

    println(s"$range")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

List(1, 4, 7, 10)
import scala.language.postfixOps
range: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 7, 10)
```

Also read: [Let’s drop postfix operators](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/lets-drop-postfix-operators/1457)

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error ...

> Error:(2, 13) recursive lazy value range needs type

... it's because you're using infix (dot-less) notation where you shouldn't.

Put a blank line before the `println()`, or a semicolon after the `toList` and it will work.

The reason for the error is that `instance.method(argument)` can be turned into ...

```
instance method argument
```

... but the compiler is often confused if you try to turn `instance.method` into ...

```
instance method
```

The compiler will look for the missing `argument` until it hits a semicolon or a blank line.