# Scala compilation error when running sys.process._

Tags: scala

I am trying to run compile below function in scala

```
  import java.io.{File, PrintWriter, StringWriter}
  def runCommand(cmd:String):(Int,String)={
      try {
        logger.info(String.format("Trying to run the following bash command: [%s]", cmd))
        import sys.process._
        val intResult:Int = cmd !
        val stringResult:String = cmd !!
        (intResult, stringResult)
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => {
          logger.error(String.format("Error in running the following bash command: [%s], Program exits!", cmd))
          val sw = new StringWriter
          e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw))
          System.out.println(sw.toString)
          sys.exit(1)
        }
      }
    (1,"1")
  }
```

But, I am getting below error:

```
[ERROR] [Error] C:\Users\cp740539\IdeaProjects\sparkscala\src\main\scala\au\com\optus\bdp\conversion\PurgingPartitions.scala:213: overloaded method value !! with a
lternatives:
  (log: scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger)String <and>
  => String
 cannot be applied to (Int, String)
```

I am not sure what is the cause of the erro?

Comment: I think you have a bug here: you execute the same command twice - via `!` and `!!` method executions. Or is this was done on purpose?

Comment: It was on purpose..

Comment: Another option that is not recommended (it is deprecated), is to enable postfix. You can read about it at [Scala's “postfix ops”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13011204/2359227).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the dot-less **instance method arg** syntax without the **arg**. The compiler goes looking for the **arg** and finds the `(intResult,stringResult)` tuple and tries to pass that to the `!!` method, which doesn't work.

Use `cmd.!` and `cmd.!!` instead.

Also: If you use a `ProcessLogger` then you can capture the exit code (`Int`), as well as StdOut and StdErr (`String`s), with a single execution of `cmd` instead of invoking it twice, as you are doing now.